Is it possible to integrate functional test case with Sonarqube and get the coverage?
I have a requirement to capture the code coverage of my selenium tests to the amount of source code in the server code (web application source code) covered.
But our functional tests are in different git repository and web application source code is in different repository.
Also our web application source code is in java script and functional test are in java.
Is there a way to integrate this with SonarQube and get the functional test code coverage.
Thanks
I want to integrate functional tests in Sonarqube and get the code coverage.
